# notepad++ regex search string and other string in previous line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am looking for regex pattern where it will search string only if another string matches in previous few lines,
for e.g.

```
abc----1
pqr----2
123----3
xyz----4
lll----5
pqr----6
123----7
qqq----8
```

so here say I want to find 123 only if we go above and first find xyz and not abc. So outout should be only matching pattern is line no 7 and not 3.
Thanks, Tim for an answer,
One more additional criteria are I wanted to replace 123 only not all line found by this pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try searching on the following pattern:

```
xyz((?!abc).)*?123
```

This matches `xyz` which is then *not* followed by `abc` anywhere before encountering `123` later in the text.  You should run the above pattern in dot all mode, so that `.*` can match across newlines.

### Demo

**Edit:**

To *replace* the `123` with some other content, say `456`, you may capture everything leading up the `123`, then replace with the captured quantity followed by the new text:

```
Find:    (xyz(?:(?!abc).)*?)123
Replace: $1456
```

### Demo

Comment: I copied this demo example in notepad++ with regex search, but it is not able to find it, basically, I want to replace 123 with some other text but with only matching criteria,i.e. if in the previous line if xyz is there and not abc

Comment: `You should run the above pattern in dot all mode` ... did you enable dot all mode as my answer suggests?

Comment: Thanks Tim, it worked but I think I missed to provide additional detail where I just wanted to replace only 123 , but with this search pattern it will find all lines but I cant replace only 123

Comment: Check the updated answer for one way to do this in NPP.